# Ubuntu 18.04 (Budgie Desktop) Video Lag (YouTube/Twitch in Chrome)

Tags: video, 18.04, budgie

I'm seeing a lot of lag while attempting to view YouTube or Twitch videos, the sound is fine but the video stops until I move the mouse.

Scrolling a web page in Chrome stable (66.0.3359.139) is laggy when using the touchscreen, two-finger scroll on the touchpad seems fine.

Lenovo G500s - i5-3230M - Intel Ivybridge Mobile graphics - 6gb RAM

Upgraded from 17.10 via software updater, 17.10 had been a clean install with nothing extra installed as this is just an internet browsing laptop.

I found a post suggesting running these commands:

```
sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extra
```

These helped in that I just have to move the mouse 1 time to get the video to play whereas before I had to move the mouse every few seconds to have the video play.

display info:

```
sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:26 memory:e0000000-e03fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Is there any other info that I can provide?

Comment: Okay here is something strange, if I run system monitor and use chrome I no longer experience the lag. Is it because it is polling the CPU? I opened it to see if there was perhaps a CPU spike that was causing the lag.

Comment: This is a known upstream issue with both chrome and chromium and is NOT distro specific - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=822549

Workaround is to turn off hardware acceleration within chrome/chromium config or use Firefox.

Comment: I didn't have this issue at all in 17.10, I will tho, check out your suggestion. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I reported it for cheese developers, but I commented that it affects many other packages. You can subscribe here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1777238

Comment: @JonDelano I want to thank you for providing the only "solution" to this probably that has actually worked for me -- opening System Monitor. Can't believe it works, but it stops the lag! Glad to see *someone* else with this problem

Comment: FYI - 18.10 fixes this bug. No need to run System Monitor any longer